# How to merge geometries and keep one color per geometry in R3F

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

The idea would be to merge several geometries and keep the color for each geometry.
An example with 3 merges polygones would be the following.

[image: Goal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possible solution**

- Set the `color` attribute for each geometry before merging them.
- Use `mesh` with the merged geometry as a parameter. Give a material as a child and activate the `vertexColors` properties.

**EXAMPLE**

Let's say we want to merge 3 polygons with one color per polygone:

```js
// Polygones to display
const zones = [{
  name:'zone1',
  coords:[[-2,0],[-2,2],[-0.4,1], [-0.8,-1.5]],
  color: 0xff0000
},
{
  name:'zone2',
  coords:[[-6,0],[-6,2],[-6.4,1], [-6.8,-1.5]],
  color: 0x0000ff
},
{
  name:'zone3',
  coords:[[4,0],[4,2],[5.6,1], [6.8,-1.5]],
  color: 0x0000ff
},
]
```

- Creating the merged geometry with the attributes would look like this:

```js
let geometries = [];
zones.forEach((zone,iZone) => {
  const shape = new THREE.Shape();
  const coords = zone.coords;
  const color = new THREE.Color(zone.color);
  const startPoint = coords[0];
  // Draw the shape
  shape.moveTo(startPoint[0],startPoint[1]);
  for (let i=1;i<coords.length; i++){
    shape.lineTo(coords[i][0], coords[i][1]);
  }
  // Create the geometry thanks to the shape
  const geom = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shape);
  // Create an attributes (same length that the indices) that will store the color state
  const indicesLength = geom.attributes.position.count;
  const aColor = new Float32Array(indicesLength * 3);
  for (let k = 0; k < aColor.length; k+=3){
    aColor[k] = color.r;
    aColor[k+1] = color.g;
    aColor[k+2] = color.b;
  }
  geom.setAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(aColor, 3));
  geometries.push(geom);
})
const newMerged = BufferGeometryUtils.mergeGeometries(geometries)
```

- And in your jsx you would have the following:

```html
<mesh geometry={merged}>
  {/* activate vertex color */}
  <meshBasicMaterial vertexColors/>
</mesh>
```

An example of the implementation can be found here: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/r3f-merged-geometries-with-different-attr-and-colors-ed0ykw?file=/src/App.js)